# Arduino Strings concatenation

Tags: arduino-mega

I am working on an arduino mega 2560 sketch.
I have to parse http query strings.

My program is concatenating strings for each http request.
And i have an http request every second during all day.

I have read that this kind of work may cause ram memory fragmentation. I am very upset about this because my program will randomly crash if there are no free ram memory.

Do you know if there is a way to initialise a string with a given memory length ?

I do not want to work with char arrays because i need indexof, substring functions and comparison with ==

Thanks

Comment: And how many of those concatenated requests do you expect to fit into the memory???

Comment: What is wrong with using the char* functions provided by C? They can do everything a String can, without the problem of memory fragmentation, and if you need a function that does not exist, it's very easy to find an implementation or create it yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a way to initialize an Arduino `String` with a given memory length: see `reserve()` method. It will generally greatly reduce or entirely eliminate memory fragmentation, if you can afford reserving a sufficient amount of memory in advance.

Just keep in mind that this is a "soft" boundary: once your string gets longer than the reserved amount, `String` will quietly resume reallocating memory with all those typical consequences.

It is not clear what you plan to do if the pre-reserved amount of memory proves to be insufficient. Fall back to "memory fragmentation"? Anything more elaborate than that will be pretty much as complex as performing manual management of a `char[]` array.

All the functionalities you requested are present for `char[]` arrays as well, might just require a few more lines of code. And it is not clear why one might "need" comparisons to be `==` specifically.

This might also be an XY problem. Why are you trying to concatenate all these requests in memory? What are you planning to do with them once you are done "concatenating"?